# AWS Snowball GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-snowball

I'm trying to send 5TB of data to S3 through AWS' snowball service.

I've received the snowball, and have connected to it through the snowball client okay. However, when I call the snowball cp command to copy files from the local server onto the snowball I hit issues. The cp command starts out fine but quickly chokes, followed by an error:

```
in thread "nioEventLoopGroup-2-45" Exception in thread "nioEventLoopGroup-2-12" Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

I'm connecting to the snowball on a linux machine and running the following command

```
bash snowball cp -r - f -l /path/to/the/archive/on/the/server s3://jobname/directory
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An intensive background Java program was interfering with the transfer. After the program finished the cp command started working without throwing errors.